# Protobuf: to use same Message name with different packages

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am using protobuf java, with following `.proto`

```
// service1.proto
option java_package = "package";
option java_outer_classname = "Proto1";
message M {
   ... // some definition
}
```

and

```
// service2.proto
option java_package = "package";
option java_outer_classname = "Proto2";
message M {
   ... // some different definition
}
```

while compile, error is thrown in `service2.proto` saying that `"M" is already defined in service1.proto`

But from package and generated code they should be `package.Proto1.M` and `package.Proto2.M`, is this conflict?

Comment: You need to give them different `package` names. These are essentially proto namespaces. You have two `M`s in the same namespace, in this case the default. That's an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "package" is also a .proto concept (not just a language/framework concept); if you need to have both schemas involved in anything, it may be useful to add

```proto
package Proto1;
```

to service1.proto and

```proto
package Proto2;
```

to service2.proto

---

Alternatively, if the `M` is actually the same in both places: move `M` to a different single file, and use `import` from both service1.proto and service2.proto

Comment: This works, and I found the detailed doc: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#packages